# ELIMINAR REGISTRO DE UNA TABLA Y GUARDAR ESE MISMO REGISTRO EN OTRA TABLA

Tags: php

Ahora vengo con este tema:

Tengo en una tabla guardados varios registros, tengo la necesidad de que cuando yo presione el botón de ELIMINAR el registro lo elimine de la primera tabla, pero que lo registre en una segunda tabla.

Aquí el código de eliminar que estoy utilizando:

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $query = "DELETE FROM fallas WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    if($resultado){
      header("location: altafalla.php");
    }
?>
```

Quedo atento a su valioso apoyo.

Comment: Por lógica, **antes** de eliminarlo debes guardarlo en la otra tabla, pues una vez eliminado ... ¿de dónde lo tomarás para guardarlo? Por tanto, implementa un código de inserción previo a la eliminación, algo como `INSERT INTO fallas SELECT * FROM fallas WHERE id=$id`. Y si esto es con todos los registros, puedes pensar en un `TRIGGER`.

Comment: mmm se podría saber cual es la finalidad de esto. Lo pregunto por que tal vez estas pensando hacerlo de modo de tener un listado de los registros eliminados, para poder recuperarlos en caso de ser necesario en un futuro. En ese caso, se realiza lo que se llama "eliminación suave" o "eliminación lógica". Lo puedes lograr simplemente agregando un columna "active" y opcionalmente otra "delete_at"  para conservar la fecha de la acción. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias primeramente por sus respuestas y su valioso tiempo. Lo hago para tenerlo como respaldo como usted bien lo menciona, ya que en la primera tabla tengo registros y la cuál contiene un campo llamado ESTATUS, este contendrá la palabra Solucionado. Sólo quiero eliminar los registros que contengan esa palabra y registrarlos en una 2da tabla.

Comment: Interesante enfoque @FranIslas, no conocía esos *tipos* de eliminación. Si el motivo de eliminación es con vistas a recuperarlo en un futuro es evidente que sería mejor hacer algo como lo que dices, pero si es algo así como un histórico no, porque la tabla estaría llena de registros *apagados o dormidos* que no tendrán mucha utilidad en ella. Creo que en base a ese criterio se puede optar por pasarlos definitivamente a otra tabla o *dormirlos* en la misma tabla si se pretende *despertarlos*  en algún momento.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya resolví el problema.